# Trying to make a procedure called map-odd-mapper in scheme

Tags: dictionary, scheme, procedure

I'm trying to make a procedure called map-odd-mapper where I take a proc that can then be applied to a list

ex:

```
((make-odd-mapper add-one) (list 14 38 29 10 57))
(15 30 58)
```

I was thinking of putting it as a let function as in 
(define (make-odd-mapper f)
(let (..........something using ret-odds to allow for the indices so that you can get the odd numbers....

ret-odds is defined as 
(define (ret-odds lst)
(if (null? lst) null
(cons (car lst) (if (null? (cdr lst)) null (ret-odds (cdr (cdr lst))))))) the point of this is just to make a proc which will allow me to apply a procedure such as add-one to a list of odd indices....

Comment: how to write the procedure i'm not sure on how to make it work so like how do i get started an such i realized that you dont need the filter and is odd since its odd on the aspect of indices.....but i'm still not sure how to write it.....

Comment: It smells like homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(define (make-odd-mapper f)
(lambda (lst) (ret-odds (map f lst))))

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be broken down into two smaller ones. At the risk of being pedantic: can you describe what these two smaller problems would be, and provide test cases for them?

Comment: well that i'm not totally sure since its supposed to be a procedure that would be make-odd-mapper....this would need to map a procedure onto the the list.....it would then have to only take the odd indices of the list to map the procedure to.....i think i might have the function down for how to make it pick the the odd indices                   it would be called (define (ret-odds lst) .....1st line (if (null? lst) null 2nd line (cons (car lst) (ret-odds (cdr (cdr lst)) with the rest of the parens but i think theres a problem with this and i cant figure it out....

Comment: i think i could design a let procedure such as (let (make-odd-mapper (map f (ret-odds lst)))) ?

Comment: Okay, I like your idea of making a function that returns the odd elements of a list.  Can you write down some test cases for such a function?

Comment: yeah so you have your function right? ret-odds for returning odds i defined it in the question.....then lets say you have this (ret-odds (list 10 3 15 8 14) and you should get (10 15 14) wont give you a sorted list but just which ones are in odd position.....and you could fiddle with the code to give you the even indices too....