# Printing elements of a list with odd indices in Scheme

Tags: scheme

so theres this code called ret-odds

```
 ex: (define (ret-odds lst)
      (if (null? lst) null
         (if (null? (cdr lst)) null
          (cons (car lst) (ret-odds (cdr (cdr lst)))))))
```

i know the problem is with the last line in that it skips over the second element of the list and gives only the 3rd.....

ex: `(ret-odds (list 'a 'g 'e ))` the procedure instead skips over the g and e and gives me null so i only end up with a so i was wondering how would i fix this?

Comment: What is `ret-odds` supposed to return?

Comment: its like this (ret-odds (list 'a 'g 'e ) and return a and e this is because its supposed to get the odd indices so 1 3 5 an so on for however big the list is....

Comment: a) It smells like homework. b) it loooks like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364838/trying-to-make-a-procedure-called-map-odd-mapper-in-scheme

Comment: It certainly looks like you and "asdfaea" are the same person. If so, trying to conceal your identity isn't a great way to garner respect....

Answer (score 2):

Your code is always skipping the last element in the list:

1. On the first invocation with `(list 'a 'd 'e)`, lst is non-null and (cdr lst) is non-null, so it takes the car (`'a`)  and does a recursive call with the cddr (which is `(list 'e)`)
2. On the second invocation with `(list 'e)`, lst is non-null but (cdr lst) *is* null. So it returns null, skipping the `'e` completely.

Something like this should work:

```
 ex: (define (ret-odds lst)
      (if (null? lst) null
         (cons (car lst)
          (if (null? (cdr lst)) null (ret-odds (cdr (cdr lst)))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `null` of your second `if` to `lst`.

```
(define (ret-odds lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) lst)
        ((null? (cdr lst)) lst)
        (else (cons (car lst) (ret-odds (cddr lst))))))
```